# Cannot for the life of me strong name a Mixed Mode DLL

Tags: strongname, mixed-mode

I have a mixed mode dll. I have set Linker\Advance\Key File to point to a valid *.snk file. Yet the dll is not strong named.

I can verify this with sn. It responds with " does not represent a strong named assembly".

There was a similar post here and it mentioned delayed signing. I've tried this to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx. Believe it may be relevant..

Comment: Turns out it was a bug with Visual Studio 2010 Service pack 1. Following the workaround fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A bug in Visual Studio 2010, Service Pack 1 was the cause.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx.